# How to animate a parallelogram in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, trigonometry, parallax

I have troubles on scrolling a Parallelogram on it's correct Direction ,because im not good in trigonometry .

I have a `DIV` with the css Attribute : `-webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);`

So it is rotated into **20** Degree.

Now on mouse wheel i want to scroll it from Bottom-Left to Top-Right Direction .

For that im using mousewheel :

```
$(window).mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
   if(delta == -1) //Scrolling Down

   else //Scrolling Up
})
```

But i have no clue how to calculate it's Right and Top Attributes to Increment Like :

```
$(".img_prlx").stop(true,true).animate({'left': '+='+x+'px', 'top': '-='+y+'px'}, 2);
```

So far i've tried this Formula but it ain't helped me :

```
var dist = 20;
var angle = 20;
var x = Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180) * dist;
var y = Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180) * dist;
```

So my **Goal** is to achieve the effect from this site : http://www.nike.com/jumpman23/aj2012/

Comment: Are you using a plugin for mousewheel? If so which one?

Comment: @Jeemusu this one https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kFZ4T/5/  <--- Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Jeemusu thanks mate ,yup that's it ,just please describe how to Move from Different Position as i need from Left-Bottom to Right-Up

Comment: I will write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your existing code and the plugin you provided, this is one method you could use to achieve diagonal scrolling.

http://jsfiddle.net/kFZ4T/7/

```
var angle = 45;   // Set the angle

$(window).mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){

    var x = Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180) * delta;
    var y = Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180) * delta;

    // Downward scroll = left,  Upward scroll = right
    $(".img_prlx").stop(true,true).animate({'left': '+='+x+'px', 'top': '-='+y+'px'}, 2);
});
```

The direction can be changed by simply changing the last line. For example changing `left` to `right` would reverse the direction so that a upward scroll would move left, and a downward scroll right.

```
  $(".img_prlx").stop(true,true).animate({'right': '+='+x+'px', 'top': '-='+y+'px'}, 2);
```

​

Answer (score 4):

You can make stuff move anywhere you'd like to on scroll without having to rotate the container, just move the elements the same amount from the left as they are moved up when scrolled.

Made a quick example of some effects here : http://jsfiddle.net/T46XJ/